# Can we overload a method which is overridden in child class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I wrote the following C++ program in visual studio 2012.

and it gave the output as follows

```
in base::fun
in child::fun
in child::fun(int)
in child::fun(int)
in child2::fun
```

while i was expecting following

```
in base::fun
in child::fun
in child::fun(int)
in child2::fun(int)
in child2::fun
```

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class base
    {
    public:
        virtual void fun()
        {
            cout<<"in base::fun\n";
        }
    };
    class child:public base
    {
    public:
        void fun()
        {
            cout<<"in child::fun\n";
        }
        virtual void fun(int i)
        {
            cout<<"in child::fun(int)\n";
        }
    };
    class child2:public child
    {
        void fun()
        {
            cout<<"in child2::fun\n";
        }
        void fun(int i)
        {
            cout<<"in child2::fun(int)\n";
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        base *ptr;
        ptr = new base();
        ptr->fun();
        delete ptr;
        ptr = new child();
        ptr->fun();
        child Cobj;
        Cobj.fun(10);
        child *Cptr;
        Cptr = new child2();
        Cptr->fun(10);
        Cptr->fun();
        int str;
        cin>>str;

    }
```

Now all i have done is just tried to overload the overridden method in child class.

My doubt is why can't I overload the fun method in child class????

Comment: That's not the behaviour I observe with GCC (http://ideone.com/ThTKYr), and it seems unlikely that VS would have such a fundamental bug.  Can you double-check you're really running this code?

Comment: Doesn't reproduce in my VS2012.

Comment: Tried on VS2013 U3 - the output there is the expected one.

Comment: Haven't tried, but is it because `child2`'s overloads aren't `public`, so the only ones visible are from `child`?

Comment: @TripeHound No, they're still overriden, but you can't call them from the outside through a `child2` pointer, only through a `child` pointer.

Comment: Is this copy and paste code or a retype?

Comment: @molbdnilo I have tried it my self I just wanted to know if we can overload a overridden method

Comment: @nikhilmehta So you *did* copy and paste that, as-is, from your editor? (Many bugs disappear if you just retype code because some typos magically go away that way.)

Answer (score 0):

Given the inconsistent behaviour with respect to `base::fun()` and `base::fun(int)` it has to be a compiler's bug.

As for the correct output, your expectation is correct! From the standard, section 10.3.2:

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a
>   class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member
>   function `vf` with the same name and same parameter list as `Base::vf` is
>   declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is
>   so declared) and it overrides `Base::vf`.

There is no mention of access specification in there.

**Note:** You should really add a virtual destructor to your base class, otherwise expect problems if you add members to the derived classes.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
Okay, I'll say it a bit different.

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void fun ( )
    {
        std::cout << "base::fun()";
    }
};

class child
{
private:
    void fun ( )
    {
        std::cout << "child::fun()";
    }
};

child* ch = new child();
ch->fun();
```

if you have such code you'll get compiler error "Child::fun() is inaccessible"
But if you change last two lines with:

```
base* ch = new child();
ch->fun();
```

Compiler will resolve your fun as public base function and function hiding won't appear.

Sorry, you **can** override public functions to be private, but never should do it.
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-inherited-public.html

I was wrong: "Your base and child classes have `public void fun(int)`, whereas your child2 has it private(because it is not preceded by any identifier: public, private, protected). So `private child2::fun()` is **different** from `public child2::fun`, which is not overriden in your class."

Comment: it does not matter once the method in base class is made public the check is dropped at run time.

Comment: `public` and `private` member functions have nothing to do with inheritance. The last sentence is plain wrong.

Comment: In your child2 class tou have two methods. First - public void fun(int); which is derived from base and is called here Cptr->fun(10);. And second private void fun(int); which is never called, because, you know, it's private. Overriden method should have same visibility. Also it is good practice to add overriden in the end of overriden function. Like this void fun(int) override. If you have done this, you've got compiler error.

Comment: Visibility does not matter for overriding in C++. This is not Java. The tip with using `override` is good though, but I am unsure if VS2012 supports it.

Comment: Check out [NVI (Non Virtual Interface)](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm). It is considered good practice to always make all virtual functions `private`.